# How do I make a notification of a downloaded pdf file?

Tags: java, android

I need to  make notification on screen after pdf file had dowloaded. File dowload? but I cannot do notification on screen.

```
 public void createDocumentAboutRegistration(User user){
    PdfDocument myPdfDocument = new PdfDocument();
    PdfDocument.PageInfo myPageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(300,600,1).create();
    PdfDocument.Page myPage = myPdfDocument.startPage(myPageInfo);

    Paint myPaint = new Paint();
    String myString = user.toString();
    int x = 10, y=25;

    for (String line:myString.split("\n")){
        myPage.getCanvas().drawText(line, x, y, myPaint);
        y+=myPaint.descent()-myPaint.ascent();
    }

    myPdfDocument.finishPage(myPage);
    
 
    String myFilePath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString();
    String nameFile =  "coupon-" + user.lastName + ".pdf";
   File myFile = new File(myFilePath, nameFile);
    try {
        myPdfDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(myFile));
        Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Coupon generated and saved in your downloads.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    catch (Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    myPdfDocument.close();


}
```

Comment: Hi! can you please provide more details regarding the exact issue that you are facing here?

Comment: You can use `DownloadManager`